# Git deletes archives on remote server

Tags: git

I have a remote --bare repository. In my .gitignore archive I have written several archives:

```
/images/logo.png
/includes/header.php
configuration.php
...
```

I have different versions of the same website, so some archives are different in different servers, thats why I wanted to ignore them and upload them separately using sftp. I keep a copy of one version of those sites in the local repository for testing.

I added them in .gitignore after creating the repository. I commited and I did:
git rm -r --cached .

I thought what it does is ignoring those archives, but when I see the archives in the remote repository, some of them are not there anymore, and I have to upload them again.

I guess i don't fully understand git, but how could I keep those archives separately? 
Would the solution be to use branches? There would be 9 branches one for each version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood what happens: When I do **git rm -r --cached .** git removes the archives that are on the remote server that were before in the git repository. If I upload those archives again and I do **git rm -r --cached .** it does not happen again because those are already ignored.

I read about keeping a different branch for every version, but is not a good practice to do. There are only a few images and config files and if I have to modify them at some point I'll just upload them using sftp for now.